# How does drawImage work?

Tags: java-me

I've been trying to draw a "game over" image but for some reason the game crashes when the image is supposed to be drawn.
I've read the API for Java ME but I don't really understand  what anchors are.
I want the image to be drawn over the whole screen.

```
if(mGameStatus==STATUS_GAME_OVER)
        {
            mGraphics.drawImage(mImgMgr.getGameOver(),0, 0, Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, it would be useful if you write the Exception thrown that causes your application to crash.

**Anchors**

The anchors in images refer to the point of the bounding box of the image to be placed at x, y.

For example, I want to set an image in position x=10 and y=20. If I use anchors TOP and LEFT, the upper left corner of the image will be placed at 10,20. With TOP and RIGHT the upper right corner of the image will be placed at 10,20.

This can be read in JavaME API, where they do a similar comparison with strings. The same apply for images except for BASELINE as Images doesn't have one.

http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Graphics.html#anchor

Comment: The problem is I can't get my netBeans to compile my app so I have to run the jar file in a external emulator which means that I can't see any exceptions thrown. It just crashes when the image is supposed to be drawn.

The picture is 513x479, .PNG